# Criar array com AJAX e mandar para outra pagina PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Existe algum método de criar um array com AJAX para enviar o valor dos input's selecionados para outra pagina onde o PHP irá receber? poderá haver vários input's dependendo da pagina, mas pagina que irá receber os valores é única para todas

```html
<div class="lista">
 <input type="checkbox" value="msc1_URL" checked>Musica 1</br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="msc2_URL">Musica 2</br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="msc3_URL">Musica 3</br>
 <!-- varias musicas aqui -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o método **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** com `.get()` você converte uma coleção de elementos jQuery em uma array JavaScript simples:

```js
var musicas = $(".lista input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
   return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(musicas); // imprime ["msc1_URL", "msc3_URL"]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lista">
 <input type="checkbox" value="msc1_URL" checked>Musica 1</br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="msc2_URL">Musica 2</br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="msc3_URL" checked>Musica 3</br>
</div>
```

Neste caso você pode enviar para o PHP via Ajax usando a array armazenada na variável `musicas` como dado a ser enviado:

```
$.post('pagina.php', { musicas: musicas }, function(data){
    // trata o retorno, se quiser
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
$.post('paginaQueRecebeMusicas.php', $('#meu-form').serialize(), function(data){
    //callback - Executa algo apos finalizar o envio. Ex. limpar o form
)};
```

HTML

```
<form id="#meu-form">
     <!-- inputs -->
</form>
```

Comment: Teria como fazer sem a necessidade de um form?